# GuiceServletConfig error

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, guice

Technologies used are GWT 2.5.1, GWTP 1-RC4, GAE 1.7.7.1, Eclipse Juno

## 1 - I have the folowing error :

Apr 23, 2013 1:35:34 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
Avertissement: **Could not instantiate listener com.MS.server.guice.GuiceServletConfig**
java.lang.**ClassNotFoundException**: com.MS.server.guice.GuiceServletConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
etc....

## 2 - I also do not know if I should include appengine-tool-api.jar in the classpath of my project ?

Tks,

Comment: com.MS.server.guice.GuiceServletConfig typo for com.ms.server.guice.GuiceServletConfig ?

Comment: Indeed, it was a TYPO ERROR...the name of the file was Guice_Servlet_Config instead of GuiceServletConfig. Thank you !